# JavaScript Closures Nested Function

Tags: javascript, function, nested, closures

Every time I call this function `a()`, I want to get the output as the square of first parameter. How should I make the value of `i` as constant, because every time at function calling it is reassigned to zero.

**Required output is 9,9,9 ie. first parameter is 3**

```js
function a(k) {
  i = 0

  function b() {
    if (i == 0) {
      k = k * k
      console.log(k)
      console.log(i)
      i++
    }
  }
  b()
}

a(3)
a(4)
a(5)
```

Comment: do you realize `i` is global? Do you realize you never do anything if i > 0?

Comment: How should I return the same  output ( first function call) when it is called 2nd or 3rd time

Comment: Well, it seems you don't want the value of `i` to be constant, or you wouldn't be incrementing it (`i++`), right?

Comment: Many ways to do it. People typically rewrite the function.

Comment: @HereticMonkey , every second time this function gets called, it should not execute, directly it should written the output of 1st parameter

Comment: You need to define the `i` variable with `let` so it doesn't get defined as a global function but only in the scope of `a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track you need to keep track if it the frist time, but you are not doing anything if it is the next time. You could keep using global variables like you are and return it if there is a value. Issue here is using a global is not the best thing to do.

```js
var prevValue = null;
function a(k) {
  if (prevValue === null) {
    prevValue = k * k
    return prevValue;
  } else {
    return prevValue;
  }
}

console.log(a(3));
console.log(a(4));
console.log(a(5));
```

Another way is to rewrite the function so it is a different function after you call it the first time. Issue here is function would have to be accessible so you can override it.

```js
function a(k) {
    var prevValue = k * k;
    a = function () {
      return prevValue;
    }
    return prevValue;
}

console.log(a(3));
console.log(a(4));
console.log(a(5));
```

It would be better to define a function in a way that there is no globals. It will encapsulate the variable so it can be read by the function and not placed in global scope.

```js
var a = (function (){
  var prevValue = null
  return function(k) {
    if (prevValue === null) {
      prevValue = k * k;
      return prevValue;
    } else {
      return prevValue;
    }
  };
}());


console.log(a(3));
console.log(a(4));
console.log(a(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `i` to be scoped only inside the `a` function by defining it with `let`, otherwise defining `i` as you are doing is the same as doing `window.i = 0` making it a **global** variable, thus, it is keeping its value even after the `a` function execution ends.

```js
function a(k) {
  let i = 0

  function b() {
    if (i == 0) {
      k = k * k
      console.log(k)
      console.log(i)
      i++
    }
  }
  b()
}

a(3)
a(4)
a(5)
```